# How do I retrieve updated user attributes from AWS Cognito after calling Auth.updateUserAttributes

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am having trouble getting the up-to-date user information from AWS Cognito either at SignIn or after updating the user attributes.

I am using aws-amplify for authentication, and sign up and login work just fine.

The problem arises on my profile page. I allow people to sign up for notifications as well as change other data in their profile. I have verified that the change is made successfully on the backend as well as in the console by logging the response.

However, when I call Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(), I get the previously cached information.

How do I retrieve the updated user attributes after receiving a successful response?

```
    async () => {
      const { email, given_name, family_name, preferred_username, "custom:notifyPredictRemind": customNotifyPredictRemind, "custom:notifyPredictResult": customNotifyPredictResult } = this.state;
      let params = { email, given_name, family_name, preferred_username, "custom:notifyPredictRemind": customNotifyPredictRemind, "custom:notifyPredictResult": customNotifyPredictResult } 
      let updateResult = await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, params) // returns SUCCESS
      let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticaterUser()
    }
```

I would expect that calling currentAuthenticaterUser at the end to return the updated user information. Any ideas how I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. There is a parameter is called bypassCache that you can pass to currentAuthenticatedUser() that will refresh the user's info. Useful for inital login and on updates to the Cognito profile.

```
async () => {
  const { email, given_name, family_name, preferred_username, "custom:notifyPredictRemind": customNotifyPredictRemind, "custom:notifyPredictResult": customNotifyPredictResult } = this.state;
  let params = { email, given_name, family_name, preferred_username, "custom:notifyPredictRemind": customNotifyPredictRemind, "custom:notifyPredictResult": customNotifyPredictResult } 
  let updateResult = await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, params) // returns SUCCESS
  let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticaterUser({bypassCache: true}) // UPDATED, NOW WORKS
}
```